# Getting dynamic text indexed by Google

Tags: javascript, html, seo, googlebot, dynamic-text

Seems like this should be a common problem, but I can't seem to find it discussed anywhere.

I'm working on a an interactive map - i.e. when you click on one of the markers, it brings up some descriptive text about that location. And I would like to make sure this text gets indexed by Google.

Currently, I'm storing all of these texts in an array, hardcoded in the script. And when someone clicks on a marker, I load the text for that marker into the DOM. The problem is Googlebot just sees it as code and does not index it.

One possible solution I thought of is to store the text in the HTML rather than as an array. But it seems a bit silly to add a bunch of invisible elements, and I'm also afraid that Google may see it as cloaking.

Any thoughts on how I can get Google to index the text?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do not hard code `display:none` in your html tags nor in css stylesheet. Set a class for descriptions and apply `.hide()` on those elements on DOM ready.
- If you have large descriptions (containing html formatting) rather than few words, You may put them in a separate file and display them using .load(). in this case it would be good Idea to use `<a href="descriptions.php?id=x">` where **x** is the id of description and handle the `<a>` tag using jquery which translates the href attribute to `.load()`. So the target page will be crawled by search engines.
- if you have few words as description, set it as `title` attribute of `<a>` tag. Titles are shown automatically or you may apply Jquery to change the way it appears. **title** attributes are SEO friendly.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful suggestions.